# nfloat 64 bit Android

Tags: android, xamarin

I am working on a project on Android Unified API Xamarin, and getting the following error.

Any idea how to handle the following error?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nfloat does not exist in Android.  It's a struct Xamarin introduced in their iOS API to allow them to seamlessly target 32 and 64 bit platforms.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason, I have got it.